# Mongodb Attendance Collction & Aggregation For Calculating Attendance

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create an application for tracking employee attendances.

Using Front End : Angular , Server: Node JS(Express Framework),BackEnd : MongoDB

I succeed to record employee attendence in mongodb, considering employee first swipe is 'IN' and
second swipe 'OUT' for a day( also can have multiple IN & OUT in day,alternate IN & OUT)

Problem am facing is to generate reports on the basis of these attendence logs i stored in the collection.

I need to generate report for an employee work duration he/she is present or absent in a day or for a particular period.

Here is my collections samples.

```
employee collections
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f120ba1578d051b20fb53e3"),
    "emp_code" : 82140,
    "emp_firstname" : "rahul",
    "emp_secondname" : "narayanan unni",
    "emp_gender" : "Male",
    "dept_name" : "office",
    "emp_designation" : "system administrator",
    "avatar" : "src/assets/images/IMG-20180302-WA0025.jpg",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-17T20:35:45.546Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-19T20:09:43.164Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f120c90578d051b20fb53e4"),
    "emp_code" : 82141,
    "emp_firstname" : "sanu",
    "emp_secondname" : "prakashan",
    "emp_gender" : "Female",
    "dept_name" : "administraton",
    "emp_designation" : "driver",
    "avatar" : "src/assets/images/IMG-20180302-WA0014.jpg",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-07-17T20:39:44.933Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-19T20:33:02.610Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

attendancelogs collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6a18a2f16b782bfdd8c427"),
    "punch_status" : true,
    "owner" : ObjectId("5f120ba1578d051b20fb53e3"),
    "chekedInTime" : ISODate("2020-09-22T15:30:42.547Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T15:30:42.565Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T15:30:42.565Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6a190ef16b782bfdd8c429"),
    "punch_status" : false,
    "owner" : ObjectId("5f120ba1578d051b20fb53e3"),
    "chekedOutTime" : ISODate("2020-09-22T15:32:30.277Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T15:32:30.290Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-22T15:32:30.290Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6b5cb2a76ecf0f77729082"),
    "punch_status" : true,
    "owner" : ObjectId("5f120c90578d051b20fb53e4"),
    "chekedInTime" : ISODate("2020-09-23T14:33:22.728Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-23T14:33:22.741Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-23T14:33:22.741Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f6b5cd8a76ecf0f77729086"),
    "punch_status" : false,
    "owner" : ObjectId("5f120c90578d051b20fb53e4"),
    "chekedOutTime" : ISODate("2020-09-23T14:34:00.123Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-09-23T14:34:00.132Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-09-23T14:34:00.132Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The query i did is, (incompelte)

```
db.employeemodels.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "attlogsmodels",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "owner",
            as: "logs",
          }
        },
    {
          $project : {
            _id:1,
            emp_firstname:1,
            emp_code:1,
            emp_secondname:1,
            dept_name:1,
            avatar:1,
            todayLogs: { $filter:{input:'$logs',as:"log",
            cond:
             { $and: [
              { $gte: [ "$$log.createdAt",ISODate("2020-09-23T00:59:59.0Z")]},
              { $lte: [ "$$log.createdAt",ISODate("2020-09-23T24:59:59.0Z")]}
              ]}
            }
          }
        }
      },]).pretty()
```

Please suggest if any better way to collect data for effient report making if am wrong this approch

I tried different aggregation stages to obtain the result,but i failed

The query i did is (incomplete)

```
db.employeemodels.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "attlogsmodels",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "owner",
        as: "logs",
      }
    },
    {
      $project : {
        _id:1,
        emp_firstname:1,
        emp_code:1,
        emp_secondname:1,
        dept_name:1,
        avatar:1,
        todayLogs: { $filter:{input:'$logs',as:"log",
        cond:
         { $and: [
          { $gte: [ "$$log.createdAt",ISODate("2020-09-23T00:59:59.0Z")]},
          { $lte: [ "$$log.createdAt",ISODate("2020-09-23T24:59:59.0Z")]}
          ]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ]).pretty()
```

Required

Report 1 : EmpDayStatus

List all employees and their status in current day

Emp_Name | department | InTime | OutTime | Duration

Report 2 : Employee Report for a particular period and/or day

Emp_Name , Emp_Code, Department
How many Absences & Presents
Each Day Total Work Duration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to change the structure of `attendancelogs` collection, because this will not produce accurate and exact report as per in and out logs, and also this is lengthy and heavy to query and processing,

#### Report 1: EmpDayStatus

- `$match` to get current day logs of `createdAt`
- `$sort` by `createdAt` ascending order
- `$group` by user / owner id, store punch in records in `pin` and store punch out records in `pout`

```
db.attendancelogs.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: ISODate("2020-09-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2020-09-22T23:59:59.999Z")
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$owner",
      pin: {
        $push: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$punch_status", true] }, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"] }
      },
      pout: {
        $push: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$punch_status", false] }, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"] }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$project` to merge both arrays (pin, pout) element in one document object, using `$mergeObjects`, `$map` to iterate loop through 0 to size of `pin` elements using `$range`

```
  {
    $project: {
      logs: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$pin" }] },
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$pin", "$$this"] },
              { $arrayElemAt: ["$pout", "$$this"] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$lookup` join employee collection with localfield _id and foreignfield _id
- `$unwind` deconstruct `user` array

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "employee",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$user" },
```

- `$project` to show employee name, logs to get required fields and duration of in and out date in minutes

```
  {
    $project: {
      emp_firstname: "$user.emp_firstname",
      logs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$logs",
          in: {
            chekedInTime: "$$this.chekedInTime",
            chekedOutTime: "$$this.chekedOutTime",
            duration: {
              $divide: [
                {
                  $subtract: [
                    "$$this.chekedOutTime",
                    "$$this.chekedInTime"
                  ]
                },
                60000 // 1000*60 in minutes
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rlfmqu79NPP)

---

Second report is totally lengthy it will take time, you can do it after taking reference of first report query.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @turivishal, sir can u please suggest a better schema to record employee attendance logs in db

Comment: it depends, i don't know about your input / logger system, try to maintain single log document for both in and out time, means manage in date and out date in single document, you have to maintain when its punch, if its `in` then insert new doc when its `out` then update existing doc with date.

Comment: Thanks for replay i follow you guidelines but having some queries like what if employee didn't do last punch out in that case this count goes in minus

Comment: @Madhav i am not sure what is your structure, you can do checkout when it comes for checkin next time.